# Printing Using a for loop

Tags: perl, for-loop

I wanted to print a statement in particular format.
example:

```
my $flag = 0;

my $new_counter = 4;

print "hello world\n";

for ( my $i =0; $i le $new_counter; $i++) {
        print "flag = $i \n";
        }
```

the output i get here is

```
hello world
flag = 1 
flag = 2 
flag = 3 
flag = 4
```

I want that the output to look like

```
hello world
flag = 1 
hello world
flag = 2 
hello world
flag = 3 
hello world
flag = 4
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You don't know how to put the `print "hello world\n"` inside the for loop...? Also, `le` is a stringwise operator, you should use `<=` which is the numerical equivalent. Otherwise you will eventually run into problems such as `2 le 10` being false.

Comment: Also `print "hello world\nflag = $_ \n" for 0 .. 4;`

Comment: @tlp actually i have made the program shorter and posted. The main script is way to complex to post. but i forgot to edit the le operator. Thanks for the update

Comment: It is not possible to suggest a solution to a problem we know nothing about. If `"hello world\n"` is a string, it can be moved and printed elsewhere, no problem. We could start guessing what the problem is, but that would be futile and be a colossal waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my $flag = 0;

my $new_counter = 4;

for ( my $i =0; $i le $new_counter; $i++) {
    print "hello world\n";
    print "flag = $i \n";
}
```

The solution is to move `print "hello world\n";` inside the `for` loop.